# A variable value is different when it is printed after structural assignment and when printed without the structural assignment

Tags: c, struct, casting, printf, shift

I do not know how to put an appropriate title to explain the problem. Thus feel free if you have a more informative title to edit.

To understand the problem, let me explain what I am doing.

I have created a structure as following:

```
typedef union __attribute__ ((__packed__)) adcs_measurements_t
{
    unsigned char raw[72];
    struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) //191
    {
        int magneticFieldX : 16;
        int magneticFieldY : 16;
        int magneticFieldZ : 16;
        int coarseSunX : 16;
        int coarseSunY : 16;
        int coarseSunZ : 16;
        int sunX : 16;
        int sunY : 16;
        int sunZ : 16;
        int nadirX : 16;
        int nadirY : 16;
        int nadirZ : 16;
        int XAngularRate : 16;
        int YAngularRate : 16;
        int ZAngularRate : 16;
        int XWheelSpeed : 16;
        int YWheelSpeed : 16;
        int ZWheelSpeed : 16;
        int star1BX : 16;
        int star1BY : 16;
        int star1BZ : 16;
        int star1OX : 16;
        int star1OY : 16;
        int star1OZ : 16;
        int star2BX : 16;
        int star2BY : 16;
        int star2BZ : 16;
        int star2OX : 16;
        int star2OY : 16;
        int star2OZ : 16;
        int star3BX : 16;
        int star3BY : 16;
        int star3BZ : 16;
        int star3OX : 16;
        int star3OY : 16;
        int star3OZ : 16;
    } fields;
} adcs_measurements_t;
```

I populate the structure by calling a function as following:

```
void adcsTM191_measurements(adcs_measurements_t* dataOut)
{
    int pass;
    unsigned char TMID = 191;
    unsigned char readBuff[72] = {0};
    pass = I2C_write(ADCS_ADDR, &TMID, 1);
    if(pass != 0)
    {
        printf("write error %d\n", pass);
    }
    pass = I2C_read(ADCS_ADDR, readBuff, 72);
    if(pass != 0)
    {
        printf("read error %d\n", pass);
    }

    dataOut->fields.magneticFieldX = (readBuff[1] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[0] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.magneticFieldY = (readBuff[3] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[2] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.magneticFieldZ = (readBuff[5] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[4] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.coarseSunX = (readBuff[7] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[6] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.coarseSunY = (readBuff[9] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[8] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.coarseSunZ = (readBuff[11] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[10] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.sunX = (readBuff[13] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[12] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.sunY = (readBuff[15] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[14] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.sunZ = (readBuff[17] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[16] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.nadirX = (readBuff[19] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[18] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.nadirY = (readBuff[21] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[20] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.nadirZ = (readBuff[23] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[22] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.XAngularRate = (readBuff[25] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[24] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.YAngularRate = (readBuff[27] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[26] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.ZAngularRate = (readBuff[29] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[28] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.XWheelSpeed = (readBuff[31] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[30] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.YWheelSpeed = (readBuff[33] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[32] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.ZWheelSpeed = (readBuff[35] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[34] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star1BX = (readBuff[37] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[36] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star1BY = (readBuff[39] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[38] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star1BZ = (readBuff[41] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[40] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star1OX = (readBuff[43] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[42] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star1OY = (readBuff[45] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[44] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star1OZ = (readBuff[47] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[46] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star2BX = (readBuff[49] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[48] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star2BY = (readBuff[51] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[50] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star2BZ = (readBuff[53] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[52] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star2OX = (readBuff[55] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[54] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star2OY = (readBuff[57] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[56] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star2OZ = (readBuff[59] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[58] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star3BX = (readBuff[61] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[60] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star3BY = (readBuff[63] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[62] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star3BZ = (readBuff[65] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[64] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star3OX = (readBuff[67] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[66] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star3OY = (readBuff[69] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[68] & 0x00FF);
    dataOut->fields.star3OZ = (readBuff[71] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[70] & 0x00FF);

}
```

Finally I print, for instance `YWheelSpeed`.

```
adcsTM191_measurements(&temp);  
printf("structure y wheel speed is: %d \n", temp.fields.YWheelSpeed);
```

This value should print a negative value and it does:

```
structure y wheel speed is: -97
```

Now here is the thing, if I print `(readBuff[27] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[26] & 0x00FF)`, which corresponds to what was populated inside the Y wheel speed variable,  anywhere inside `adcsTM191_measurements(adcs_measurements_t* dataOut)` it does not print this negative value. Rather it prints the maximum value of an unsigned char (65,535‬).

```
int y = (int) (readBuff[33] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[32] & 0x00FF);
printf("inside struct y is: %d", y);
```

I am expecting that storing inside the structure does a kind of implicit cast and so it prints the negative value as expected. How is it doing it? How can I print the correct value without the use of the structure?

Comment: 65,535 is not the maximum value of an `unsigned char` in your C implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to C 2018 footnote 128, it is implementation-defined whether a bit-field defined with `int`, as in `int YWheelSpeed` is signed or unsigned. Since your implementation is showing a negative value for it, presumably it is signed, and therefore, as a 16-bit signed integer, it can represent values from −32,768 to 32,767.

We can also deduce that `int` in your implementation is more than 16 bits, likely 32 bits (from the fact that “65535” is printed in one case when `int y` is printed with “%d”).

Consider this assignment:

```
dataOut->fields.YWheelSpeed = (readBuff[33] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[32] & 0x00FF);`
```

In this expression, `readBuff[33]` and `readBuff[32]` are converted to `int` by the *usual promotions*. `0x00FF` is also an `int`.

If we suppose `readBuff[33]` is 255 and `readBufff[32]` is 159 (which is 2<sup>8</sup>−97), then the value of the expression on the right side of the `=` is 65,439 (which is 2<sup>16</sup>−97). In an assignment, the right operand is converted to the type of the left operand, which is a 16-bit signed integer. In this case, the value, 65,439, cannot be represented in a 16-bit signed integer. C 2018 6.3.1.3 3 tells us “either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.”

A common implementation of this conversion is to produce the result modulo 2<sup>16</sup> or, equivalently, to reinterpret the 16 low bits of the `int` as a two’s complement 16-bit integer. This produces −97. Since your implementation subsequently showed −97 for the value, presumably this is what your implementation did.

Thus, `dataOut->fields.YWheelSpeed` is assigned the value −97. When it is later printed with:

```
printf("structure y wheel speed is: %d \n", temp.fields.YWheelSpeed);
```

then the *default argument promotions*, which include the usual integer promotions, convert `temp.fields.YWheelSpeed` from a signed 16-bit integer with value −97 to an `int` with value −97, and “-97” is printed.

In contrast, suppose `(readBuff[33] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[32] & 0x00FF)` is printed with `%d`. As we saw above, the value of this expression is 65,439, so “65439” should be printed.

The question states:

> Now here is the thing, if I print `(readBuff[27] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[26] & 0x00FF)`, which corresponds to what was populated inside the Y wheel speed variable,… it prints the maximum value of an unsigned char (65,535‬).

However, `(readBuff[27] & 0x00FF) << 8 | (readBuff[26] & 0x00FF)` is not the value that was assigned to `YWheelSpeed`, which is presumably the “Y wheel speed variable”. `YWheelSpeed` was assigned from `readBuff` elements 32 and 33, not 26 and 27. Thus we should not be surprised that some different value is printed rather than 65,439.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have 32-bit `int`, so the initialization never sets the sign bit. But the structure field is only 16 bits, and will be sign-extended when it's converted to `int` for the `printf()` call.